# How do I break an input into individual characters in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to be able to take an input that could be anything from A-Z or 0-9 and of an indefinite quantity of characters and put them into a list. Here is an example of the code I am envisioning.

```
    number = input()

    num_list = break_string(number)

    print num_list
```

Comment: This can be done incredibly simply by using a list comprehension. I'm hesitant to post an answer though as this appears to be homework, and you haven't posted what you've tried.

Comment: This can be done even simpler via list constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension when you need to turn an iterable (string in this case) into a list:

```
print([c for c in "hello"])  
['h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o']
```

Each character is considered an element of the string. The part before `for` is what's put into the new list. In this case, it's just taking a character and putting it into the list unchanged.

Comment: why not just `list("hello")` ??

Comment: @coder tbh, I didn't know you could do that; haven't written Python for awhile. That definitely would work to.